# How to store and access sensitive data in NodeJS backend during Docker build

Tags: node.js, docker, google-cloud-platform

I'm working on a web app in monorepo with Angular for the frontend, NodeJS (with TypeScript and Express) for the backend and MongoDB Atlas for the database. Here is the structure of the project:

[**Structure of the project**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FI2FS.png)

In the .env file in the backend folder, I store some sensitive data such as the username, password and host of the MongoDB Atlas database. This file is not pushed on my repository, I only pushed a .env.template file that contains the same variables but with mock values.

I would like to deploy my application with Google Cloud so I configured a Google Build trigger that automatically build my Docker image, push it to the container registry and deploy using Google Run. Everything is working fine, except for the .env file because I'm not sure how to assign the database config values.

**How can I securely define the .env file so my backend can get the credentials for the database ? If you have any more advice about improvements I could make to my project don't hesitate because that's my first attempt to build a whole app and deploying it.**

I read about Secret Manager and Substitution variables but I'm not sure how to correctly use one of them, or even if it's really a secure way to handle sensitive data. I tried to set up substitution variables in the Google Build trigger but it doesn't seem to work because I only get empty values.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
# Use Node.js image for building the app
FROM node:18-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /usr/app
# Copy package.json and package-lock.json files to the working directory
COPY package*.json ./
COPY backend/package*.json ./backend/
COPY frontend/package*.json ./frontend/
# Create the .env file for the backend and fill it with Cloud Build substitution variables
COPY backend/.env.template ./backend/.env
RUN sed -i "s/__MONGODB_ATLAS_USERNAME__/${_MONGODB_ATLAS_USERNAME}/g" ./backend/.env
RUN sed -i "s/__MONGODB_ATLAS_PASSWORD__/${_MONGODB_ATLAS_PASSWORD}/g" ./backend/.env
RUN sed -i "s/__MONGODB_ATLAS_HOST__/${_MONGODB_ATLAS_HOST}/g" ./backend/.env
# Install dependencies for both backend and frontend
RUN npm ci --ignore-scripts
# Copy the entire monorepo to the working directory
COPY . .
# Build the app
RUN npm run build

# Use a smaller base image for the production build
FROM node:18-alpine
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /usr/app
# Copy the production-ready code from the build stage
COPY --from=build /usr/app/backend/dist ./backend/dist
COPY --from=build /usr/app/backend/.env ./backend/.env
COPY --from=build /usr/app/frontend/dist ./frontend/dist
# Install production dependencies only for backend
COPY backend/package*.json ./backend/
WORKDIR /usr/app/backend
RUN npm install --omit=dev --ignore-scripts
# Expose the port the backend server is running on
EXPOSE 3000
# Start the backend server
CMD ["npm", "run", "start:prod"]
```

And here is my cloudbuild.yaml file:

```
steps:
  # Build the container image
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    args: ["build", "-t", "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/app:$COMMIT_SHA", "."]
  # Push the container image to Container Registry
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    args: ["push", "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/app:$COMMIT_SHA"]
  # Deploy container image to Cloud Run
  - name: "gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk"
    entrypoint: gcloud
    args:
      - "run"
      - "deploy"
      - "app"
      - "--image"
      - "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/app:$COMMIT_SHA"
      - "--region"
      - "europe-west1"
images:
  - "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/app:$COMMIT_SHA"
```

And my .env.template file:

```
MONGODB_ATLAS_USERNAME="__MONGODB_ATLAS_USERNAME__"
MONGODB_ATLAS_PASSWORD="__MONGODB_ATLAS_PASSWORD__"
MONGODB_ATLAS_HOST="__MONGODB_ATLAS_HOST__"
```